# Unable to traceroute on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, networking

I have setup a brandnew Ubuntu 14.04 instance, with a public IP, with a security groups that allows all inbound and outbound traffic using all protocols on all ports from/to any IP.
I have installed traceroute.

It seems that I am unable to traceroute any domain (have tried amazon.com and google.com). I get the following output:

```
traceroute to google.com (74.125.136.102), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 * * *
2 * * *
3 * * *
4 * * *
5 * * *
6 * * *
7 * * *
8 * * *
9 * * *
10 * * *
11 * * *
12 * * *
13 * * *
14 * * *
15 * * *
16 * * *
17 * * *
18 * * *
19 * * *
20 * * *
21 * * *
22 * * *
23 * * *
24 * * *
25 * * *
26 * * *
27 * * *
28 * * *
29 * * *
30 * * *
```

However, ping seems to work fine, and wget and curl as well.

```
PING google.com (173.194.65.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ee-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.65.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=10.3 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.65.101): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.65.101): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.65.101): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=10.3 ms
^C
google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.326/10.435/10.549/0.165 ms
```

Is there any obvious setting that I am missing?

Comment: What happens if you do traceroute -I google.com?

Comment: Yes, that works as expected. So am I right to assume that there are issues with TCP SYN packets? Any idea if there is any setting to enable?

Comment: No, by default, traceroute uses UDP. The router that responds is responding with an ICMP time exceeded message.

To test with TCP, use the -T flag.

I'm not sure why you're not getting the normal response, but I'd look over the security groups again, and perhaps check the network ACLs.